# Symfony 1.4 - blank page instead of 404

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Where i can search the errors for this problem? 
I have:

**http://www.mypage.com/module/action**
and
**http://www.mypage.com/frontend_dev.php/module/action**

this working ok (this action and module exist)

if i open:

**http://www.mypage.com/frontend_dev.php/module/actionewr**

then i have error:

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
Action "module/actionewr" does not exist.
stack trace
```

this is OK, but if i open:

**http://www.mypage.com/module/actionewr**

then i have blank page. all is white, in source is empty.

how can i set 404 in Symfony 1.4? Now i can't check where this redirect my and modify this?

if i set in settings.yml:

```
  .actions:
    error_404_module:       default
    error_404_action:       error404
```

this working ok, but i would like add for this own module and action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it in `settings.yml` :

```
  .actions:
    error_404_module: module_name
    error_404_action: action_name
```

Comment: thanks, but if i set default this working ok, but if i set own module and action then i have blank page

Comment: yes, i clear cache, but i dont have log for index.php. i have error log only for frontend_dev.php

Answer (score 1):

**You can configure it in settings.yml :**

.actions:

```
error_404_module: module_name
error_404_action: action_name
```

**And in index.php :**

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check error logs of your web server. Normally symfony shows a nice error page if anything goes wrong on the prod environment.

Read a bit more about it here: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_sub_default_modules_and_actions

(It's about symfony 1.2 but in 1.4 it's similar).

Comment: i dont have access for apache log :( if i use default symfony page then i this is ok, but if i use own action and module, then is blank page

Answer (score 0):

I've added this code:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration:
              :getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);
```

into index.php.